# Database Design for University Admission Points Calculation with Varied Weightage

Tags: sql, database, model

I'm currently working on a database design for a university admission system, and I'm facing a challenge with the calculation of admission points. Each university calculates admission points differently based on high school subject scores.

Here's a simplified example of the issue I'm facing:

I have a `University`  model that has a relationship with a `Course` model.
The Course model has a field called admission_points.

The admission points are calculated based on 7 subjects from high school, each with its own weightage.
For example, let's consider the following subject scores from high school:

- English: 70
- Home Language: 80
- Mathematics: 76
- Life Orientation: 40
- Physical Sciences: 60
- Life Sciences: 90
- Geography: 56

In one university, this combination of scores might result in 36 admission points, while in another university, it might result in 38 admission points due to their different weighting systems.

My question is: How can I incorporate this varied admission points calculation into my database design in a way that is flexible and maintainable? I want to be able to store the weightages for each subject used by each university and calculate the admission points accordingly.

Comment: Create a weighting table that holds the university, course and weighting? You seem to have already answered this in your question so I’m not clear what the actual issue is that you’re facing?